# explanation of the output of the code

Tags: c++, global-variables, output

I was recently asked to consider the output of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int gvar;
int main (void)
{
     cout << &gvar << endl;
     while (true);
     return 0;
}
```

This code is compiled and an executable is generated. If this executable in run 2 terminals in parallel. what would it print.

My reply was that it would print 2 different addresses. But on running, I found out in both the terminals same address was printed.

Can somebody explain why this is happening. I know that might be due to virtual memory but I am not able to put the pieces together.

Comment: I think this is more related to compiler than any language.

Comment: More than likely you are getting a memory address that is in the executable's stack space and if that is the case then it should be the same address.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not that it matters, but no that variable shouldn't be on the stack. It's a global variable, after all.

Comment: Actually it may or may not print same address.

Comment: @unwind I didn't mean the actual stack.  I couldn't think of the way to say the processes memory space at the time.

Answer (score 5):

It is very clearly due to virtual memory, yes.

The addresses seen by code like this are virtual. Since each process has its own table of virtual-to-physical mappings, the virtual addresses need not be unique inside each process.

Comment: but does that mean that every time it would return same address. As in, it could have printed a totally different address which on mapping would have returned a different physical memory address. ?

Comment: @ShReYaNsH Yes, it could, but those are implementation details in the operating system. It can choose to randomize the virtual addresses used, or not.

Comment: so what I understand is that it is merely a co-incidence that the same address is getting printed. Though seemingly same addresses will be mapped to different addresses in physical memory. Is that correct ?

Comment: @ unwind Thanks for pointing to the correct question. Helped a lot !